# Activity strange behavior when started from Android Notification

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications, instance

I am experiencing a strange behavior with my android application when dealing with a notification that is created from a BroadcastReceiver when a C2DM message arrives on the mobile device. The flow I am executing to experience this behavior is the following one:

1. Start my application, DashboardActivity is displayed;
2. Close application either by pressing home button or back button;
3. Receive the push message and create the notification;
4. Click the notification item and the activity BookingOfferActivity is launched;
5. Close the BookingOfferActivity either by pressing home or back button or calling finish()
6. Long press home button and select my application from recent applications
7. BookingOffcerActivity is displayed instead of DashboardActivity

The BookingOfferActivity is being launched from the notification using the following code:

```
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, BookingOfferActivity.class);
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putSerializable("booking", booking);
notificationIntent.putExtras(b);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
long[] vibrate = {0,100,200,300};
notification.vibrate = vibrate;
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(AppUtil.getNextPushIndexBooking(), notification);
```

BookingOfferActivity is defined in the AndroidManifest this way:

```
    <activity android:name=".activity.BookingOfferActivity" 
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

and my DashboardActivity is defined like this:

```
    <activity android:name=".activity.DashboardActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name" 
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" 
              android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The reason I am calling it a strange behavior is that I would like to start DashboardActivity whenever my application is started or restarted by the user, not by the notification item. So after closing, finishing or destroying BookingOfferActivity and reopening by application by accessing recent opened application (long press on home button) or accessing the launcher icon on the application list, I would like to see the Dashboard.

I create a question similar to this one but I didnt provide too much details, so I closed the other one and opened this one with more data.

Many thanks for any guidance on how to solve this problem

T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I suppose that in your scenario second activity just go to the top of activity stack and will be shown until application wont be killed. We have approximately same problem and solv it in easy way: Notification start main(first) activity with extra "go to second immediately". in `onCreate` of first activity check this extra and start second activity if needed. With this solution you should be careful with pressing back button - if you dont want to show first activity in case of "notification start" you should care about it in `onResume` of first activity

Comment: Hi @Jin35, I implemented your idea, it seems fine to me, but how can I remove the second activity from the top of the activity stack after finishing it? It seems that the activity will be there even if I hit home or back button. Should be I using some kind of flag for that? Thank you

Comment: if you call finish() for second activity it will be removed from activity stack.

Comment: that is what I am doing, when I am done with the second activity I am calling finish(), but the activity is always being on the top of the stack. I tried to start the second activity using Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP and NO_HISTORY but it didnt work both ways. I am kind running out of alternatives here. Thank you for your help.